# Let $I = [0,1]$ and compare the following three topologies on $I^{2} = I \times I$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $I = [0,1]$ and compare the following three topologies on $I^{2} = I \times I$.

$\mathscr{T}_{1} = $ The product topology on $I \times I$

$\mathscr{T}_{2} = $ The dictionary order topology on $I \times I$

$\mathscr{T}_{3} = $ The subspace topology on $I \times I$ inherited from the dictionary order topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

I have read a few solutions to this problem but I am just not understanding it.  I feel like I am reading Chinese.  If someone wants to type up something clear that will help me understand, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know any theorem like "if $B_1$ is a basis for the topology $T_1$, and $B_2$ is a basis for the topology $T_2$, if (*some condition on $B_1, B_2$*) then $T_1 \subset T_2$ "?

Comment: I do...I am just having a really hard time grasping what these topologies "look" like as far as how they are represented in basis form.  I don't know why but this material is not making sense in my brain!

Comment: It would be really helpful to make a drawing of your square, and trying to draw the elements of the three bases. For example, in the firsta case you have small rectangles, while in the third you have small vertical lines... Well, in the second case it's a bit complicated...

Comment: That is a good suggestion.  I actually have in my notes from class a picture of the open sets for the second one.  So is the third similar to the second except only containing the open intervals?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easy if you are good at drawing. I'll just make a sketch of why $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$, but they're all the same ideas.

The summary is: the "small" basic opens on $(I^2,\tau_2)$ are just open vertical line segments and these are contained in any open basic subset with the product topology.

Take an open rectangle $R=(a,b)\times (c,d)$ contained in $I^2$, which is just an open basic of $\tau_1$, and $(x,y)$ in that rectangle, so $a<x<b$ and $c<y<d$.

Consider $c_y,d_y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $c<c_y<y<d_y<d$.

And consider the open basic subset of $\tau_2$:

$$((x,c_y),(x,d_y))=:\{(x',y')\in I^2:(x,c_y)<'(x',y')<'(x,d_y)\},$$

where $<'$ is the dictionary order on $I^2$.

In fact, that open basic is just the open vertical line segment with endpoints $(x,c_y)$ and $(x,d_y)$ centered at $(x,y)$. A little draw shows it is contained in $R$, and hence $(x,y)$ is an interior point of $R$ in the topology $\tau_2$. Then every open basic subset of $\tau_1$ is in $\tau_2$. Thus $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$.